# Retrieve empty submitted input data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, input, request, nullable

I'm trying to update a specified resource in my laravel application using data submitted through a classic form, using PUT/POST method:

```
Model::find($id)->update($request->all());
```

This works fine, except the case where I submit the form with an empty input. Then I'll have all values in my request except the empty input's data, so the updating process isn't complete.

I know I can check if each request parameter exists and if it doesn't, assign it a NULL value but I'm trying to avoid that and I want to know if Laravel retrieves empty data that could be access through Request.

Comment: if (!empty($request->all())) ??

Comment: I want to be able to access empty data as well, right know `$request->all()` only retrieves populated form data

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298213/pass-empty-fields-on-the-update-method-using-laravel-request

Answer (score 1):

```
//remove the _token from the request
$data = request()->except(['_token']);
// then with array_filter remove empty array values from $data
$result = array_filter($data);
//finally update your record
Model::find($id)->update($result)
```

EDIT :

You want to keep all the fields even the null ones ?

Add rules to your request and mark your "optional" request fields as nullable if you do not want the validator to consider null values as invalid, here is an example of rules :

```
public static $rules = [
'first_name' => 'nullable|string',
'last_name' => 'nullable|string'
];
```

Comment: `$result = array_filter($request->all())` would be easier.

Comment: yes ! if the Model does not contain a column named "_token " otherwise it will be a serious problem :p

Comment: Why would I remove empty values when I don't even get them? I don't want to remove empty values, I just want empty values to be accessible through $request the same way non-empty values are!

Answer (score 0):

Check with array_filter(request()->all()).
i.e.

Model::find($id)->update(request()->all()):

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using request->all() set the fields explicitly with a fallback.
something like:
`Model::find($id)->update([
  'this' => $request->this ?? '',
  'that' => $request->that ?? '',
]);`

A little more cumbersome but it will get the job done.