# Pass empty fields on the update method using Laravel Request

Tags: laravel, forms, input, request, submit

I'm getting data through a classic submitted form but for some reason I don't get all the input's data in request and it only updates the received ones.

```
Model::find($id)->update($request->all());
```

This is a bit problematic because I have multiple nullable fields in my database and sometimes I want to pass empty fields (i.e when a user clear an input then submit the form)

Do you know a way to pass empty fields to the Request as well?

Comment: they aren't stripped out, if the browser submitted it, they are there.

Comment: what do you get when you var_dump($request->all())?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, Laravel transforms the `''` values to `null` by default through the [ConvertEmptyStringsToNull](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.html) middleware. Check your Kernel:

**app/Http/Kernel.php**

```php
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    // ...
];
```

This middleware do the following:

```php
protected function transform($key, $value)
{
    return is_string($value) && $value === '' ? null : $value;
}
```

As you can see, if the given attribute has a value `''` it will be transformed to `null`.

So, to avoid this you could just comment that middleware in the Kernel file. But be aware of this, because this will be applied to your entire application.

Comment: My problem is that I don't get the request input at all

Comment: That is just because of this. If the input value is a `null` Laravel will 'ignore' its existence. If you comment that line it will keep the `''` values.. ergo, this attributes will be present in your request.

Comment: On my both web application and API ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware is active (not commented), yet when I log the request on my web application I can see empty fields with null value and on my API I don't see them at all. Why is that?

Comment: That middleware only changes the value to an explicit `null` value. The inputs are still there, they are not 'ignored'.

Answer (score 1):

**[Input Trimming & Normalization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization)**
Laravel version > 5.4 already has these features included:

---

**For versions < 5.4:** make a new middleware with following code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    foreach ($request->input() as $key => $value) {
        if (! $value) {
            $request->request->set($key, NULL);
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and assign it to the routes or controller's methods you want it to take place:

```
Route::post('/route/{id}', [
   'middleware' => NewMiddleware::class,
], function (Request $request, $id) {
    Model::find($id)->update($request->all());
});
```

---

**REMEMBER:** `create()`, `update()`, etc. methods work on fields in `$fillable` array in your model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'contact', ];
}
```

Or if you want to exclude some fields and include rest, use `$guarded` array instead:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['details'];
}
```

If your field is not in the `$fillable` array in "Model" class, the `update()` method will not work for that field!!!

Reference: **[Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `array_merge()` like with this code as i use that

```
$contentCategory->update(array_merge($request->all(), ["FIELD1" => '',"FIELD2" => '']));
```

or test this code:

```
$request->request->add(['FIELD1' => '','FIELD2' => '']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to make it work: on my web application I have disabled ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware (commented it) so when I log the `$request` I get empty values `''` and on the API, `$request` logs `null` value for each field.

Comment: was not this what I recommend you to do?